# Is there a way to break the {{each}} looping in JQuery Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

Is there a way to break the looping defined in the JQuery Template , the one which we used to break any normal loop.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It should be possible. Can you post the data and the condition you want to break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just pass in a smaller collection containing only the values that you do want to loop over? In general, templates should be "dumb" and contain as little business logic as possible.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply, i completely agree with you.But in my case i am getting a whole array from a service directly into my instance object which i need to iterate using template.But there is one condition i need to show only top 9 records and if there are more records , i need to show a "And More" Link.So i was thinking that is there any way to do this.

Comment: Ah, so you're basically looking for row pagination using a template?

Answer (score 0):

your templates should not be smart enough to break loops. it should render data, and not process anything. there may be a 'proper' way to do this, but this might work if you need to get er done.

sudo code...

```
continue = true;
{{each}}

{{if continue}}
{{expressionToCheckIfContinue()}}
TEMPLATE BLAH
{{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

set the continue var to false (from within expressionToCheckIfContinue) when you want to break.

Comment: but this is horrendous and should not be done if youre using jquery templates properly.